# installing mysql there's no bin folder

Tags: python, mysql, bin

After installing `mySQL` version `8.0` and typed in terminal `mySQL -u root -p` 
as headfirst python  mentioned. but doesn't work.
I googled it and I found, the answer is path addition. 
but didn't find `bin` folder. How to add path? or how to find bin folder?

Comment: More details needed: What's your OS?(Expected: Windows, Linux or others) How do you install it?(Expected: via package manager, via binary release, via graphical installer, etc.)

Comment: Also, don't just say "it doesn't work", you are expected to include the phenomenom, in text (better, since it is indexable by a search engine) or image.

Comment: Find bin folder in your MySQL installaion directory. Then add that directory to the PATH variable (Google for "windows environment variable").

Comment: sorry, windows 10 pro ver. python 3.6. downloads  this fileon the website-> mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.12.0.msi  , 'mysql -u root -p' <- typed in terminal  korean error message  'mysql' term isn't identified cmdlet, function, script file or executable program name  ~~~ + mysql -u root -p
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mysql:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: ok. thank you.  i'll handle it.

Comment: It's sure that "add the folder that contains 'mysql.exe' into the PATH variable" will fix the problem.